# Proper handling of base url in Yii2

Tags: yii2

In Yii2 basic and advanced templates,

```
 Yii::$app->request->baseUrl
```

accesses the base url of the app.

But how does one **set** the base url in Yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enforce it you can just set it:

```
\Yii::$app->request->baseUrl = 'http://whatever.com';
```

It will override whatever was obtained from the actual request (`Request::getScriptUrl()`) until you set it to `null` again.